# Is it possible to reduce antenna power or wifi signal strength on my FIOS G1100 access point?

Tags: networking, wireless-router, wireless-access-point

I placed my FIOS G1100 access point in addition on the side of my house. A separate R6400 serves the rest of the home. Masonry separates the two, so devices don't communicate reliably unless they've selected the appropriate access point.

My goal is to get my laptops and phones to select the R6400 instead of the G1100 when in the main part of the home, without disabling the antennas on the G1100 entirely.

I've read that reducing the signal strength on one access point can help devices to select the other access point, but I don't see a way to do so in the G1100 management UI. Any help appreciated.

Comment: If there is no setting in the router firmware then you out of luck.

Comment: Sticking some metal cladding on the wall where you don't want the signal to permeate might also reduce the signal inside.

Comment: Partially wrap or surround the router in aluminum foil. Basically, opposite of what [these guy did to boost wifi](https://curiosity.com/topics/aluminum-foil-really-can-boost-wi-fi-speed-heres-how-curiosity/)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I have read the [manual](https://www.verizon.com/cs/groups/public/documents/adacct/fqgrouter-userguide.pdf) for you and I could not find such a setting, so unfortunately, you are out of luck. If you require this feature, an option would be to buy a dedicated WLAN access point.

When it comes to your sticky WiFi issue, there is no real solution without the drivers of the device being intelligent enough to switch when a stronger network is available. Unfortunately, most WiFi software will stick to a network as hard as it can.

My suggested solution is to use 2 different SSID instead if using Roaming and switching manually.